# UCMA endpoint without config store replication

Tags: windows, visual-studio, lync, ucma

I am trying to build a solution using the UCMA sdk but do not have access to the config store. Is it possible to use UCMA without it? I have a username/password I can use to log into the lync network and thought perhaps I could access things like that.

Comment: An emulator sure would be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you can do this with a UserEndpoint. It doesn't require any replication with the config store (as long as you have a username and password which you've said you have).

I have a comparison between application & user endpoints here: http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2014/01/ucma-endpoints-choosing-between-application-and-user-endpoints/

and a worked example of using User Endpoints to send an IM here:http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2013/03/creating-ucma-applications-with-a-userapplication-instance-example-sending-ims/

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to run this code:

`An exception of type 'Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.TlsFailureException' occurred in Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The target principal name is incorrect`

Any Idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

UCMA applications can run in two different modes:

1. [Untrusted (Client) Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn466052.aspx).

In this mode you can't create "[ApplicationEndpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn466053.aspx)"'s but you can create "UserEndpoint"'s if you have the sip address and password for the user.

2. [Trusted (Server) Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn466051.aspx).

In this mode you can create "[ApplicationEndpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn466053.aspx)"'s and you can create impersonate any user with "UserEndpoint" without needing the user password.

There are two types of setups for Trusted Application's.

2.1. Auto Provisioned Trusted Application
This one is very easy to setup with code but very hard to setup to run on the machine.  I don't really recommend this setup as the machine setup requirements are very high.

2.2. Manual Provisioned Trusted Application
This one has a lot more "setup" code but is easier to setup a machine to run on.  I would recommend this setup as I find it far easier to setup overall.

Both types of Trusted Applications require you to [setup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn466114.aspx) the Trusted Application details within Lync before you can run them.

Which UCMA application setup you use is based on how you configure the [CollaborationPlatform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.collaborationplatform_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr.aspx) instance.

**Basic Untrusted (Client) Application:**

```
var clientPlatformSettings = new ClientPlatformSettings("lync.front.end.server.address", SipTransportType.Tls)
var collaborationPlatform = new CollaborationPlatform(clientPlatformSettings);
...
await Task.Factory.FromAsync(collaborationPlatform.BeginStartup, collaborationPlatform.EndStartup, null);
```

**Auto Provisioned Trusted Application:**

```
var serverPlatformSettings = new ProvisionedApplicationPlatformSettings("lync.front.end.server.address", "trusted application id")
var collaborationPlatform = new CollaborationPlatform(serverPlatformSettings);
...
await Task.Factory.FromAsync(collaborationPlatform.BeginStartup, collaborationPlatform.EndStartup, null);
```

**Manual Provisioned Trusted Application:**

```
var certificate = CertificateHelper.GetLocalCertificate("trusted application pool qfdn");
var settings = new ServerPlatformSettings("lync.front.end.server.address", Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").HostName, trusted_application_port, trusted_application_gruu, certificate);
...
await Task.Factory.FromAsync(collaborationPlatform.BeginStartup, collaborationPlatform.EndStartup, null);
```

There are a lot of missing details.  Once you know what type of UCMA application you want to develop, you can search on the internet for specific examples of that type.